# Regarding Bad Sectors on Hard Drives

Tags: hard-drive, hardware-failure, disk-space, hard-drive-recovery

Modern hard drives utilize a 4,096 byte sector size when storing information. For a hypothetical exercise let's say we are attempting to store 40,960 bytes (10 sectors) worth of data on the drive. These 40,960 bytes represent a single file we are attempting to store. Now let's assume one of these sectors failed on the drive. In situation A we just had the file stored as-is (e.g. really-huge-document.pdf) and in situation B we had split the file into ten subsections (e.g. really-huge-document-pt-1.pdf through really-huge-document-pt-10.pdf). Disregarding an attempt to effectively put back the data into the original form, does situation A represent a full loss of data while situation B represents only loosing 10% of the data? Or is the data recovery dependent on the type of data being stored and/or the error correction methods implemented on the drive?

Comment: If only 1 sector has died then the resulting either case is the same. You can recover (potentially) 90% of the total data. In the case of the single monolithic file you are at the mercy of the file format itself, and whether it has any active or natural error recovery features, the *data* will be there in either case. The problem here is that splitting the files up is not fundamentally the same as a single file, each one of those files has "header" information describing their format and file type, a single file would have this only once.

Comment: How easy a single file is to recover depends on where exactly the error is. An error in the last sector means that almost everything is readable, an error in the first means you may have lost critical information about the entire document that makes the rest of it unreadable.

Comment: @Mokubai: Depends on the file. For example for PDF the document's directory is usually at the end and if lost then the sequencing of the pages is lost.

Answer (score 1):

There is not one answer to your question.
It all depends on the structure of the damaged file and the extent of the damage.

In the example you used, PDF is very vulnerable to a partial destruction, because
its internal structure is hierarchic. If the upper-level data is lost, then
the file cannot be repaired.

On the other extreme you will find the simple text file,
where breaking it into pieces will only mean that one piece is lost and the others
will remain as stand-alone.

I would recommend that you do not try to cut files into pieces, since this is not
a sure protection. You could still lose the whole file by losing only one of
the pieces.

I would instead recommend keeping the files in the shape that is the easiest
to use, and to concentrate rather on having backups.

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer depends on the hard drive recovery software that you use. Steve Gibson with the Gibson Research Center is a pioneer in data recovery. If you read through his website concerning his SpinRite product, he discusses in depth how his software can partially recover files where other products will not recover a file if one sector is bad.

Here is an example excerpt where he talks about partial file recovery:

> Accept Partial Data: If the Dynastat analysis is unable to perfectly
>   reconstruct the sector's data, it will at least be able to identify
>   the data bits that differed from one reading to the next. This allows
>   it to greatly minimize the uncertainty within the sector's damaged
>   area and to recover most of the sector's 4096 individual data bits.
>
> SpinRite will log the name of the file whose sector was not completely
>   recovered and replace the file's completely unreadable sector (which
>   any other software would have simply discarded) with this "mostly
>   correct" now-readable sector so that all but a few data bits of the
>   file can still be read and used.
>
> This is obviously a huge improvement over losing the entire file due
>   to one of its sectors being completely unreadable.

Here's one where I think he sheds light on your question by describing a method used:

> Rather than giving up when a sector can't be read, or rather than
>   taking whatever data the drive might be willing to begrudgingly yield,
>   the DynaStat system accumulates a comprehensive statistical database
>   about the behavior of any troubled sector's data through the
>   accumulation and classification of up to 2,000 individual sector
>   rereads. By understanding the unlock/relock behavior of the drive's
>   data-to-flux-reversal encoder-decoder, and by processing the sector's
>   data "tails" after encountering a defect of any kind, the Dynastat
>   technology "reverse engineers" the sector's original data from the
>   statistical performance profile of the unreadable sector's flux
>   reversals. As a result, SpinRite can often completely recover data
>   that would otherwise have been utterly lost. Needless to say, no other
>   utility has ever incorporated such technology.

You can read more here:

https://www.grc.com/srrecovery.htm